# Windows 8.1 Black screen + flickering mouse after update

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bios, safe-mode

So, my Windows 8.1 Computer announced that it needed to update, so I hit "Update and Shutdown". Normally, everything would be Ay-Okay, but apparently not this time.

This time, whenever I boot my computer the following happens:

1) I get a black screen with a flickering mouse, no displays.

2) When I plug it into my TV via HDMI, same result, just on both screens.

I've tried booting into safe mode, but I still get a blank screen.

I'm really at wits end here, and nobody elses issues that I've seen match this.

**TO CLARIFY:** The error happens *AFTER* the `POST` boot. I see a Windows 8 Splash-Screen, loading bar/circle thing, and then just a black screen.

What's happening to my PC, and how can I fix it (without safemode, because that's not working, either).

Comment: use system restore to go back to the point before you installed the updates. Do you use 3rd party themes and the UX file patcher?

Comment: Yes - I'm asking for a friend, but I'm 99% sure he uses custom themes. IS this the problem, I've never encountered anything like it before!

Comment: don't use a tool which cracks Uxtheme DLLs. Use this tool which patches them in memory: http://uxstyle.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating to Windows 8.1. I discovered that the third party Start Menu app *StartisBack* was installed but not compatible with Windows 8.1. I solved the problem by updating the app.