# Windows 8.1 flickering Black Screen after update, without safe mode

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, video, display-driver

I think I will pull my hair out of my head before I'll solve this problem.

I decided to do an Update in my Windows 8.1, cause it wasn't updated a year already, and cause of some problems that I had in some programs and I thought it will deal with it, BUT, that was a bad idea. Let's begin with the most interesting part, I had the same problem when my PC had to stay offline for 3 months, because I wasn't home and I was using my Laptop most of the time, but then the problem was solved with installing an old Video Card, so Windows just reinstalled the video driver, and then I placed back my VGA, but now this isn't working anymore.

Yesterday I was updating my Windows by small parts, somewhere taking a list of 10-15 updates by one time from a list of 280, a few times it worked repairing boot problem from an USB stick (You just cannot take and update Windows without a startup issue or another problem, hate it....), but now even repairing from stick isn't working.

So I took my Laptop and tried googling for this, and found this threads:
[First](https://superuser.com/questions/812263/windows-8-1-black-screen-flickering-mouse-after-update)
[Second](https://superuser.com/questions/818449/windows-8-1-black-screen-and-no-safe-mode)
[Third](https://superuser.com/questions/750351/flickering-black-screen-after-kb2919355-windows-8-1-update-1-no-os-access)

... but non of them worked for me. **So this happens when I boot my PC:**

*AsRock Logo > Windows Logo > Black screen > in 1 minute or so there is a flickering mouse on the screen*

In safe mode is the same problem. So I cannot run Safe mode.

What I tried so far:
1. Repairing it (cannot repair it, it cannot find any problems)
2. Restoring, there are no restore points

I cannot just reinstall it, because there is a lot of information to be saved from it, and it would be time consuming. I have this system backed up and updated from Windows 7 on 2 machines for a few years, trying to keep it clean without reinstalling.

My PC specs, if it would be of help:
CPU: i7-3770K
VGA: Radeon 7970
RAM: 32GB
PSU: Chieftec 1000W
SSD 128GB for Windows
MB: AsRock p67 Pro3

Answer (score 1):

If system in an inconsistent state, e.g. some components updated, some not, it would be very hard to fix.

Maybe its time to reinstall.

You will have to spent some days in saving your files, reinstalling system and programs but at the end you will have a fresh computer.

I would recommend you buy external disk and use it for regular backups.
Restoring from backup can be done in less than an hour, on click - just compare the effort to saving, reinstalling.....

Note:

You can always try offline repair of system files.

sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows

c: is where boot files are

d: is where Windows is

C: and D: could be the same drive, adjust letters to your mappings.

No guarantee that this can help.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I thought about one more thing, what if I'll try to update to Windows 10 from a stick? Or I can brick it harder?